# What are the CSS @font-face ascent-override/descent-override percentages relative to?

Tags: css, font-face

The CSS [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) rule has two properties called [`ascent-override`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/ascent-override) and [`descent-override`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/descent-override). These properties can be either `normal` or a percentage. But if you set a percentage, what are they relative to?

1. Are they a multiplier of the font's built in ascent and descent metrics? So use `100%` to replicate the font's ascent metric?
2. Are they a percentage of 1em, or of the font's [em-square](https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align#lets-talk-about-font-size-first), so for example, to replicate an ascender of 680 units you'd use `68%`?
3. Something else?

Comment: From the example [here](https://publishing-project.rivendellweb.net/overriding-font-metrics-with-css/) and I created demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wgLnfma3/), I think it is related from itself. Try to add some character to the font name - for example `Playfair Display` to be `Playfair Displays` and the fallback font (local) will be use and you will see the `ascent-override`, `descent-override` in action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 2. A percentage of the used font-size. If the value of the em square was 1000 units then 68% would equate to 680 units. See [Example 39](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-4/#example-7315a3e2) from the spec.